# How to encode placeholder value?

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder

Is there any way to set the placeholder dynamically not just a string but with a special characters?

I am creating a custom input control in which I allow user to set the placeholder of input of his/her own. User may set the placeholder value with some sspecial characters (say unicode characters which will be parsed as string).

I achieved the above desired behvior by doing the following things.

- Create a span element and set innerHTML as HTML Input with entered placeholder.
- Now get the placeholder value from the span's children and set the value to my custom input.

Refer below snippet.

```
function parse(placeholder) {
  var spanEle = document.createElement("span");
  spanEle.innerHTML = '<input  placeholder="' + placeholder + '"/>';
  var hiddenInput = spanEle.children[0];
  customInput.setAttribute("placeholder", hiddenInput.placeholder);
}
```

For example, if the placeholder is `"Search &#8220eye color&#8220"`, the parsed value would be `Search "eye color"`

However, this solution is failed for the below case.

if the placeholder is `'Search "eye color"'`, the parsed value should be `Search "eye color"` but the actual result I obtained is `Search`. It does not parse after the double quotes.

How to achieve this? I have reproduced this with native HTML5 input. Please have a look at the below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nj8fct?file=index.js

Kindly help me to resolve.

Comment: Please post your code *here*.

Comment: @deceze. I have edited and added code snippet

Comment: Why do you have placeholder strings with HTML entities in the first place? Is that a necessity?

Comment: Yes. It is. I want my custom input to behave as like HTML5 input. If we provide placeholder="&#8220" for html5 input (inline binding). It accepts and shows double quotes.

Comment: But then one of your inputs is HTML encoded and the other is not. You have an unsolvable problem then. Your input needs to be well defined. Is it already HTML encoded or isn't it? If you don't know, you'll either get syntax errors if you _don't_ encode it programmatically (as you do), or you'll see HTML entities in the UI if you _do_ encode it programmatically.

Comment: Please note that I have only one input and I am setting the placeholder of input after getting the string value obtained from the user. So the problem here is, if user provides any special characters as a placeholder value, I need to parse that before setting to placeholder and I did it as mentioned in my question. I could not if the user provides with some complicated values (as like double quotes stated in my problem)

Comment: If the user gives you "&quot;", then your placeholder should show "&quot;", exactly as the user typed it…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230016/discussion-between-jeyanth-and-deceze).

Answer (score -1):

```
"<input  placeholder=\"" + placeholder + "\"/>"
```

u can use '' before quotes or double quotes

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work out.